# Use tr:nth-child(odd) and tr:nth-child(even) selectors only on nested top tables

Tags: php, html, css, pseudo-element

I want a zebra striped table.
The data is extracted from the database and every instance creates a new table.
I want the zebra-striped on the `<table>` level. this would mean that every other `<table>` element gets a different color.

I tried to add a class to my `<table class="oddeven">` but this still does the changing on every tr.

Here is the code I use it on:

```
<?php
                global $wpdb;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'group' AND meta_value='$group'";
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                echo'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">';
                    foreach( $results as $result ) 
                    {       
                        $post_id = $result->post_id;
                        $company_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'company_name', true); 
                        $address = get_post_meta($post_id, 'address', true); 
                        $postal_code = get_post_meta($post_id, 'postal_code', true); 
                        $city = get_post_meta($post_id, 'city', true); 
                        $phone = get_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', true); 

                        echo '
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="oddeven">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="75%">
                                            <strong>'.$company_name.'</strong>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="4"><img class="table_image" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/arrow.png"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            '.$address.'
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            '.$postal_code.'  '.$city.'
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            '.$phone.'
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
            ?>
```

This is the styling:
(while typing this I realise that this is on tr:level)

```
.oddeven tr:nth-child(odd){ 
background: #ffffff;
}

.oddeven tr:nth-child(even){
background: #000000;
}
```

I hope I make myself clear

Comment: I think we'd need to see the brief example of the output HTML nested tables to be able help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your foreach loop to a for loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
    $result = $results[$i];
    ...
```

Then you can figure out if the current row is even or odd by testing if `$i % 2 == 0`. If that evaluates to true, then add an 'even' class; else add an 'odd' class.

Comment: You sir are a genius. I hope to reach a level like that someday :-) Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to propagate the change to child tables, you can also enforce the same color on the children :

```
.top tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}   

.top tr:nth-child(odd) tr {
    background-color: red;
}

.top tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}   

.top tr:nth-child(even) tr {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I assume that's what your want since you already have stripped rows on your nested tables
Or maybe I got it wrong, you might have to explain what the `<table>` level is, since your have nested tables.